# Outlook automation / Object Model query (Python) - unique ID for each email?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2012, outlook, ironpython, msdn

I've been using the MSDN to build a simple app that automates some Outlook 2010 basics.
It's going well, but I'm just stuck at something simple I think.

My question is this:
I've been able to get objects based on email folders, and even emails, and iterate through them, outputting email subjects as strings, or folder names as strings.

I've been able to get the info into listboxes, but I'm wondering, let's say I want to do something with a specific email I have selected in a listbox, does anybody know if the mailitem object has a property like a unique ID that I could have hidden somewhere or in a SQLite DB that I could use as a reference to do something with said email instead of having to search through the folder again by subject or name ?

The same question kinda applies to what I'm doing to find a specific folder, looping through the inbox folder and if I find the folder by name, then output that folder object. Surely there's a more efficient way to search by name in one step, without looping through folders to find subfolders etc ?

This isn't necessarily a python question, more about how the objects work.

Any help is much appreciated

MSDN Links:

Outlook Object Model Reference
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff870566%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Folders Object
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff870798%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Items Object
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff870897%28v=office.14%29.aspx

MailItem Object
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff870912%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for [EntryID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866458%28v=office.14%29.aspx).
But please be aware that this ID is only unique/constant per .pst file.